# Headless webkit for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, webkit, headless, headless-browser

Do any of you know of a headless webkit wrapper for .NET?

I've looked at [WebKitDotNet](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) but it does not seem to work in headless mode.

Answer (score 3):

I remember reading this post form Steve Sanderson some time ago -

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/

I should add that I've never tried anything mentioned in the post and I'm not sure how it will work with Webkit but thought it might help

Comment: sure. however, for real world applications, HtmlUnit sucks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jasmine Headless Webkit:

https://github.com/giggio/jasmine-headless-webkit-dotnet/

http://nuget.org/packages/jasmine-headless-webkit-dotnet/