# Evaluate Html/javascript from c#

Tags: c#, javascript, dom

I have been tasked with finding a solution to quite a novel issue. I have a variety of httpclient calls that I have to make in order to authenticate against a 3rd party vendor. However, part of this process involves dynmaically generated values being created in javascript and passed to a form, which is then posted to the 3rd party. As I'm using the httpclient class, I cannot obviously generate/run the javascript and thus the process comes to a halt right here (the posting of these values creates an important authentication cookie for an intermediate step).

So, I'd like to be able to take this simple html, which contains a form and some javascript, and have my c# code evaluate this and then retrieve the values that javscript has assigned to the form. I'd then use these values and continue with the workflow processes.

I could take a clunky route and use the webbrowser control. However, as this is being used in a non visual environment, I'd like to be able pass the html string into some sort of emulator and receive the parsed html back as a return. Below is an example of the simple html that I'd be dealing with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testLoad() {
            document.forms[0].elements[0].value = "some guid id plus the date:" + Date.getDate + 'some random js value';
            document.forms[0].elements[1].value = decodeURIComponent(document.forms[0].elements[1].value);
            document.forms[0].elements[2].value = decodeURIComponent(document.forms[0].elements[2].value);
            // optionally submit -or just get the returned form values and post from htmlclient
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }</script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
</head>
<body onload="testLoad()">
    <form method="POST" action="/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="test_id" value="idstuff" />
        <input type="hidden" name="test_123" value="encoded value" />
        <input type="hidden" name="test_another" value="1.01" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Once the html has been returned from the *emulated* process, I'd then use HtmlAgilityPack to grab the form values that have been populated by the javascript function (testLoad()) and progress to the next steps.

Am I aiming too high here, or has this bridge been crossed a few times. I've looked at http://wiki.awesomium.com, csExWB, jint and a few others, but none seem to take the really simple approach that I'm hoping for here. Think of my quest as being able to use the initial html as a parameter and have the *emlulator* return the *patched* html.

Hope the above is clear - I am wishing to evaluate the html/js from a serverside process and then move onto the next process within my c# workflow!.

**[edit] -** this looks VERY promising: http://www.tomdupont.net/2013/08/phantomjs-headless-browser-for-net-webdriver.html. I've taken the tips here and am using PhantomJs with Selenium... so far, so good!!

[oh and just to point out, this is not for any sinister use, the 3rd party in question just doesn't yet have a b2b api in place to permit the interop that we require between us]

Comment: How complex is the Javascript? Is that an accurate example you've provided? Because you could just rewrite that in C# and use a simple HTTP post using the values gained via the HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: hi there, unfortunately, this is of course a simplified version of the javascript. the *real* javascript runs some meaty validations, ^'s as well as calling some core js functions against looped data

Comment: In that case, [IronJS](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS)

Comment: i did see that earlier when looking, however, it appears to only avaluate ecma script and not the full web stakc (i.e. html plus script in single unit)...thanks tho

Comment: It really does sound like you want the functionality of the WebBrowser control, without using WebBrowser control. Why do you feel it would not fit the requirement?

Comment: it doesn't fit the requirement mainly becuase I will be baking this into our b2b api (which I will replace once the 3rd party has changed their platform). our side of the api will live on an azure server and thus the process needs to be encapsulated (*preferably*) inside a non visual process that has a low startup and memory footprint. that said, don't think i haven't tried with old mr wb!! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which can be scripted via JavaScript and [run as an external process from C#](https://gist.github.com/DotNetNerd/5635371):

Comment: +1 looks promising. do you have any 1st hand experience with this?? Altho i love link juice, nothing whacks me more than 1st hand use and anecdotal evidence of it's efficacy... as said tho - looks like a contender

Comment: @jimtollan: no firsthand experience here, sorry

Comment: no worries, i will of course try this out. i'll then drop an update. however, a range of other answers/comments will hopefully narrow my quest...

Comment: hey, i updated the original post to point to a setup page for .net and phantomjs -works really well!!

Answer (score 3):

[AngleSharp](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/AngleSharp/) also contains a short demo (project) that connects [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) (a JavaScript interpreter, completely written in .NET) to it. Both are PCL projects and they work together without problems. That should provide everything that is usually used in JavaScript / the DOM.

A very simple example looks like:

```
static void SimpleScriptingSample()
{
    //We require a custom configuration
    var config = new Configuration();

    //Including a script engine
    config.Register(new JavaScriptEngine());

    //And enabling scripting
    config.IsScripting = true;

    //This is our sample source, we will set the title and write on the document
    var source = @"<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head><title>Sample</title></head>
        <body>
        <script>
        document.title = 'Simple manipulation...';
        document.write('<span class=greeting>Hello World!</span>');
        </script>
        </body>";
    var document = DocumentBuilder.Html(source, config);

    //Modified HTML will be output
    Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);
}
```

This will print the (serialized) DOM, which already contains the modifications (such as a new title and the inserted span element).

Comment: thanks for this florian, i'll take a look over that as it looks like a nice simple implementation - plus i imagine it can mix 'n match with htmagilitypack, `post` documentbuilder

Comment: Thanks for your great work @Florian. But it seems your whole documentation on AngleSharp is outdated. can you please update the documentation? for example I couldn't figure out to register javascript engine. the config.register() gets requester as argument. There is no code example...

Comment: It is true, a lot of things just recently. I'll update the documentation as soon as I can (hopefully still this week). In the mean time I can recommend you the samples at https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Samples -- they work with the current version and also showcase JavaScript integration.

Comment: What's the replacement for DocumentBuilder?

Comment: Hi @GavinWilliams use `BrowsingContext`. It has methods like `OpenAsync`. Ideally, you can just stream a source. If you have an HTML `string` then use the response builder pattern like `context.OpenAsync(res => res.Content(myHtmlString))`

Comment: @Florian Rappl Thank you for your help on here and also on GitHub recently. You've been a great help with usage of your library!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'll need a headless browser to execute the html/javascript. [Take a look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759153/headless-webkit-for-net)

I would prefer [AngleSharp](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/AngleSharp) over HtmlAgilityPack though.

Comment: alas, htmlagilitypack is used throughout the project, so no option to change